# How can I bind a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm using the Bing map SDK in my WPF application and the XAML looks like:

```
<m:Map 
  x:Name="MyMap"
  Grid.Row="1"            
  CredentialsProvider="KEY"  
  ZoomLevel="{BINDING MapZoomLevel}"
  Mode="Road">
```

The code behind:

```
private int mapZoomLevel;
public int MapZoomLevel { get { return mapZoomLevel; } set { mapZoomLevel = value; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MapZoomLevel); } }
```

But this aint working. I guessing it is because I've already bound the Map by setting `x:Name`. The problem is that I can't remove the x:Name since I'm doing some setup in the view but is there a workaround? I would like to be able to bind the ZoomLevel of the map somehow

Comment: Why is it "not working"? What does Name have to do with ZoomLevel..? Should it really by uppercased `BINDING` and not `Binding`? What happends if you set `, Mode=TwoWay` on the ZoomLevel binding?

Comment: You're going to need to define "not working" a little better. But for starters, is the data context set properly?

Comment: Are you using WPF FrameWork 4.5?? otherwise it wont work.

Comment: NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MapZoomLevel); works only with Framework 4.5 or above

Comment: Are you setting your VieWModel properly?

Comment: Something may also be overriding your binding after the fact. You mention setting the name, so something else is probably referencing this element later on in the code. Could you provide a snippet of how this name property is used?

Answer (score 0):

In order to data bind, you need to do a few things:

1) You must set the `DataContext` of the `UserControl` or `Window` to the object that contains the property that you want to bind to. That could be like this (in the `UserControl` or `Window` code behind) if that object is a separate view model class:

```
DataContext = new SomeTypeOfViewModel();
```

Or like this if the property is declared *in* the code behind:

```
DataContext = this;
```

2) You must implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or implement `DependencyProperty`s - you seem to have implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, but you must ensure that you have done it correctly.

3) You must provide a valid `Binding Path`... `BINDING` is *not* valid, so an appropriate `Binding Path` for you might be this (depending on where you have declared your property):

```
<m:Map x:Name="MyMap" Grid.Row="1" CredentialsProvider="KEY" 
    ZoomLevel="{Binding MapZoomLevel}" Mode="Road">
```

Please read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for the full story.

Answer (score 0):

based on your tags you are using Caliburn Micro with this?  Datacontext is already set with viewmodel/view from the framework.  ZoomLevel="{Binding MapZoomLevel, Mode=TwoWay}" is required.